# Почему wordpress грузит хостинг?

Tags: wordpress

Привет всем!

По каким причинам может грузить сервер WP. Проверил лог, подозрительных запросов нет (например отсылки к wp-login.php).

Из ошибок вот такая:

> [Tue Jun 07 09:45:12 2016] [error] [client 188.143.232.27] PHP
>   Warning: 
>   fopen(C:\Bitnami\wordpress-4.3-0/apps/wordpress/tmp/custom-aCcqUt.tmp)
>   [function.fopen]: failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in
>   /home/c/cl89443/public_html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-ftpext.php
>   on line 117

На данный момент нагрузка составляет 97.84 cp из 50.

Что посмотреть? Как проверить?

Comment: Может там есть какой нибудь плагин автоматически делает бэкапы.

Comment: @ВалерийЕмельянов да единственный плагин который это делает, это  wp super cache, других нет. но до него тоже было

Comment: Напиши в тех. поддержку на хостинг, они направят в нужное направление 100%

Comment: @ВалерийЕмельянов написал, может ли сам шаблон так себя вести?

Comment: Может, они тебе скажут где именно проблема, если хостинг нормальный конечно

Comment: Так же вспомнил такую ситуацию, сайт грузил сервер из-за файла логов. Он постоянно был огромного размера. Попробуйте покопать в этом направлении

Comment: @ВалерийЕмельянов логи мало занимают. видимо тема такая

Comment: Что делать - прежде всего не использовать виндозные недосервера. Сайт должен работать в том окружении, где будет эксплуатироваться. Кроме того нужно использовать темы и плагины только из оф каталога. (Блин... вопрос 3хлетней давности...)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй отключить WP_Cron, он довольно тяжелый)

Comment: Ни в коем случае этого нельзя делать!

Comment: Можно. Отключаешь вп-крон и настраивает обычный крон на wp-cron.php

Comment: Что за бред... Сам-то понял что написал? :)

Comment: Я то понял) попробуй погуглить) прирост очень большой

Comment: Ты даже не понял какой бред ты написал :) Отключить нормальный запуск, а потом ЕГО ЖЕ запускать через серверный крон. Ну не бред? :)) И не гугли, не читай всякую ересь недоумков. Читай правильные ресурсы и слушай правильных людей. Напр. посмотри доклады Ковшениных на вп.тв. https://wordpress.tv/page/2/?s=kovshenin

Comment: Если ты знал как запускается ядро вордпресса то понял бы, что крон запускается при каждом заходе на сайт

Comment: Отключив ВП-крон на сайте будут копиться разные неотработанные задания.

Comment: А ты смешной.. :)) учи матчать, учи.

Comment: Крон-задачи не стоят в очереди а выполняюстя с интервалом, а соответственно не могут копиться от слова абсолютно никак

Comment: @NazaryFerbey поговорим когда узнаешь, что невыполненная задача остаётся невыполненной (как раз из-за блокировки крона) и пишется в базу. При этом регулярно пытается выполнится.

Answer (score -1):

1. Поставь query_monitor, посмотри что там с запросами в базу и
   php-ошибками. обработка ошибок занимает много памяти.
2. Отключи Heartbeat API
3. Отключи крон
4. Поставь кеширование w3 total cache если разбираешься, wp rocket 
   если не хочешь играться с настройками и что бы работало
5. Напиши в саппорт хостинга, пускай посмотрят и скажут что грузит
   больше всего

Comment: Кроме совета использовать **query-monitor** (а не "query_monitor") всё остальное - лажа и опасность.

Comment: heatbeat API постоянно дергает ядро аяксом, крон выполняет кучу лишних действий на каждом ините,  кеширование - даже не обсуждается. Если не понимиаешь работу ядра и не умеешь базово конфижить сервер что бы не было проблем с безопасностью - не пиши ерунду.

Comment: Учи матчасть. Что ни ответ, то ламерская ересь.